# Another "The name 'itembutton' does not exist in the current context" (WP8, XAML)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I know that this question has been posted about a thousand times, but I did not find a solution that solved my problem.

I've got a LongListSelector with this `ItemTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Button x:Name="itembutton" CommandParameter="{Binding ItemID}" Content="{Binding ButtonCaption}" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Click="ItemButtonClick"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

So what happens is simply that I get this beautiful error message that I posted in the title. And I do not have a clue, why?!

```
private void ItemButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (sender == this.itemButton) {
    ....
```

Comment: Is it case sensitive? In the view it is "itembutton" in the code "this.itemButton".

Comment: no, did not help. though it's a very poor style :(

Comment: You seem to be approaching the problem wrong. You're trying to use a CommandParameter, but that's for use with a Command, not a Click event. And I don't understand why you're wanting to do `sender == this.itemButton` anyway. Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

From the `DataTemplate` it looks like you're showing this button in a container like a `ListBox` or `LongListSelector`.

That means that there isn't an `itembutton` in `this` scope (presumably `this` is either `UserControl` or `PhoneApplicationPage`): there is in fact one for each of your `ListBoxItems`!

You'll have to find another way of finding your button.

**Update**:
You should find that the `DataContext` of your button matches the item of the list it is contained in. That's probably the easiest way of proceeding: however if all else fails you can use the `Tag` property as you suggest.

Like:

```
private void ItemButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var theButton = (Button) sender;
    var myItem = (TypeOfAnObjectInMyList) theButton.DataContext;
    doSomethingWithMyItem(myItem);
```

Comment: Hm, yeah you're right. There are -possibly- lots of these buttons.
But how can I find them then? By `button.tag`? What is the correct way to handle such a prob?